# Event on launch/stop of visible part of application

Tags: android, android-activity

Stackoveflow!

I have an application with `sticky` background service and visible part, consisted of several activities.

I need to track start and stop of visible part (all activities). 
For example:

- When user starts MainActivity, Service receives LocalBroadcast that tells it to **start something**.
- When user rotates screen, Service must **not** receive anything.
- When user goes to SecondActivity, Service again must **not** receive anything.
- When user closes ALL ACTIVITIES, Service gets LocalBroadcast telling it to **stop something**.

If I use `Activity`. `onCreate` and `onDestroy`, or `onStart` and `onStop`, I get events related to lifecycle of single activity. Also I get events related to screen rotation.

I also cannot use `Application`. `onCreate` or `onTerminate`, as they will not trigger because of service running in the background.

I need to track real start and stop of entire application *except* service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

> When the last client unbinds from the service, the system destroys
>   the service (unless the service was also started by startService()).

So each `Activity` should `bind()` to the service, in `onCreate`, and `unbind()` in `onStop`/`onDestroy`

Now to fix the problem with the orientation changes, you can check for `isFinishing` in the `onStop`/`onDestory` callback 
(see: [How to distinguish between orientation change and leaving application android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620841/how-to-distinguish-between-orientation-change-and-leaving-application-android))

and also put some flag in `onSaveInstanceState` callback, so that in the following `onCreate` you can check for the existence of that flag, and act accordingly (refresh the binding, or avoid calling `bind()` again)